# DEP0001 when deploying to mobile (device or emulator)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I've had DEP0001 on and off with every build of Windows on early experience, but can't find anything to help this time. No application will deploy. Steps to reproduce:

Windows: Windows 1607, (14393.10)
Visual studio: Visual Studio 2015 Community, Update 3
Preparation: Boot Windows, run repair on Visual Studio, boot Windows, sfc / scannow finds no errors, boot Windows.

1. Create a new Windows Universal application, accept the defaults for Min and Max version.
2. F9, and it runs locally.
3. Change the target to an emulator, F9, it starts the emulator and then gives DEP0001 : Unexpected error -2147467259
4. Change to targetting ARM, F9, and "The project needs to be deployed before it can be started"

So none of the usual answers about deploying to mobile seems to apply (because it won't deploy to an emulator either). Any suggestions as to how to continue welcome.

Comment: Did you install the latest Anniversary SDK?

Comment: The Anniversary SDK is part of Visual Studio Update 3, I think

Comment: please, be sure that you have installed this SDK

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled, 10586.212. Deploying to phone gives "The specified module could not be found (0x8007007E)"

Comment: I have version 10.0.14393.33, this is latest version

Comment: Thanks Andrii, I went on to uninstall and reinstall VS as some of it looked a bit wrong. Now deploying okay.